# Unexpected trouble comparing numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm writing a helper method that adds a class to an element depending on whether two numbers are equal to eachother.  My code is as follows:

```
<% for note in @company.convertible_notes.each %>
    <% if note.id %>
        <li class="tab <%= note_nav(params, note.id) %>"><%= link_to "#{note.security_series} #{note.security_class} Note", convertible_note_convertible_notees_path(note) %></li>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

note_nav calls the following helper:

```
def note_nav(params, note)
    "active" if params[:controller]=="convertible_notees" && note.to_s==params[:converible_note_id].to_s
end
```

Now the surprising thing is that I cannot get the expression `note.to_s==params[:converible_note_id].to_s` to register true.  Even when I know the two numbers being compared are both "1".  I checked it using my log:

```
logger.debug "are they equal? #{note.to_s==params[:converible_note_id].to_s} note.id is #{note} note params are #{params[:convertible_note_id]}"
```

Which yields the following log entry:

> are they equal? false note.id is 1 note params are 1

I would guess that they're two different types but given that I've converted both of them `to_s`, I don't know how that would be an issue.  I've used this exact same technique on a few combinations of other models and have been completely error free.  Any idea as to what might be going on?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Isn't this rather a typo in the first condition?: `if params[:controller]=="convertible_notees"` - note the "notees"... That would make the whole condition always fail...

Comment: @borama no that's right, albeit a little weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your test

```
"are they equal? #{note.to_s==params[:converible_note_id].to_s} note.id is #{note} note params are #{params[:convertible_note_id].to_s}"
```

`:converible_note_id` and `:convertible_note_id` are other keys, a type error

Answer (score 0):

You could also get that output if one of the variables contains non-printing characters:

```
note = "1\000"

params = {
  convertible_note_id: 1
}

puts "are they equal? #{note.to_s==params[:convertible_note_id].to_s}"
puts "note.id is #{note} note params are #{params[:convertible_note_id]}"

--output:--
are they equal? false
note.id is 1 note params are 1
```

To see what's really in a string, you should always use inspect():

```
p note.to_s, params[:convertible_note_id].to_s

--output:--
"1\u0000"
"1"
```